# Google Maps don't show up

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to create an app with google maps. I used google maps api v2 but the maps don't show up. I just see a gray screen with buttons for zooming.

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure that error is not in API key..

This is my code..

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.examplemaps.rs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.examplemaps.rs.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel = "signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.examplemaps.rs.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.examplemaps.rs.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.examplemaps.rs.Home"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyB5aBact***myAPI key"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Home.java:

```
 package com.examplemaps.rs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Home extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And activity_home.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home" >

  <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found error. In Android Manifest I've replaced READ_GSERVICES with:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Now, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I never tried it but I'm pretty sure a MapView should be inside a MapFragment (or a MapActivity if it were an Activity).

Have you tried to google MapView Fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

You say you are sure the the error isn't with the API key, but have you checked that your API key corresponds to the account you are using to compile the project? (i.e did you get hold of your API key using a debug token or a release token).

Another thing to try (if you haven't already of course) is on-device testing. I have had issues myself before with grey tiles on emulators, but on real devices there has been no such issue.

Otherwise, [Asaf Nevo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092770/asaf-nevo)'s answer may be more accurate, `MapViews` should tend to be in a `MapActivity` or similar, and make sure you are building the **Google APIs** version of Android. See [MapFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment.html).

Taken from [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/):

- **Maps are now encapsulated in the MapFragment class**, an extension of
  Android's Fragment class. Now you can add a map as a piece of a
  larger Activity. With a MapFragment object, you can show a map by
  itself on smaller screens, such as mobile phones, or as a part of a
  more complex UI on larger-screen devices, such astablets.
- Because **maps are encapsulated in the MapFragment class**, you can
  implement them by extending the Android standard Activity class,
  rather than extending the MapActivity used in version 1.

Comment: I tried it on real device also and with both API keys. The same problem occurred...

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the "Maps" app is actually installed on the device?  i.e. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps&hl=en

I had a few old devices that didn't have Maps installed, and had the same symptoms (gray screen with zoom buttons but no map content).

Comment: Hm...I've never had to do that before when installing it fresh.